# I need help on how to minus out the value in an object with a random number that is given

Tags: java, object, random, numbers

I need help on how to minus out the value in my object which is (25) when a random number (num) has been generated. I have written my code below but there seem to be a problem in my last line.

```
StickBag s1 = new StickBag(25);

int randNum = 1 + (int)(Math.random()*2);

int num = 1 + (int)(Math.random()*11);

for(int i = 0; i < 25 ; i++)
        {   

        if(randNum == 1)
        {
            System.out.println("Computer player 1 chooses " + num + " sticks. ");

            StickBag = StickBag - num;

        }
```

For e.g. If a random number that is generated is 5 , then the total value in my object (25) will minus the value that was generated randomly (5) and therefore my object will then have the value 20 in it

I hope i have made myself clear

Comment: s1.setValue(s1.getValue()-num); // getter setter for the attribute `value` in `s1` instance of StickBag.

Answer (score 3):

The trouble with the line

```
        StickBag = StickBag - num;
```

is that StickBag is the name of a class. You actually want to refer to an instance of that class.

In your program, you have an instance of StickBag called `s1`. Therefore, what you probably want to write is something like this:

```
        s1.stickCount = s1.stickCount - num;
```

That's with the assumption that `stickCount` is a public attribute of the class StickBag, and that it's what gets initialized to the value 25 when you do `new StickBag(25)`.

Let me suggest that you rename `s1` to something more expressive, such as `gameBag`. That might not suit your particular concept, but whatever it is, try to use words rather than single letters and numbers.

Also, `num` is pretty vague and could be renamed to something more specific, such as `playerMove`. And you might want to use the `-=` operator to perform the subtraction. If you were to apply all three of my suggestions, the line would look like this:

```
        gameBag.stickCount -= playerMove;
```

If `stickCount` is private and you have to access its value with `getStickCount()` and set its value with `setStickCount()`, you would write the following.

```
        gameBag.setStickCount(gameBag.getStickCount() - playerMove);
```

Note that in this case you can't use the `-=` operator. (Some programming philosophies insist on using getters/setters and others don't. The debate isn't germane to this question and you can find plenty of material on it elsewhere.)